# install4j: Failure Strategy "Ask User" in unattended mode

Tags: install4j, silent

I have used the failure strategy "Ask user whether to quit on failure" in some actions. In unattended mode install4j interpretes this seemingly as "Continue on failure".

How can I determine, that it shall instead use "Quit on failure"?

I have tried to use the response.varfile for this, but have not found out, which entries I would have to do to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as of 6.1.5. In 6.1.5 we will add a boolean installer variable `sys.actionFailureUnattendedQuit` that forces unattended installers to quit when an action fails and the failure strategy is configured to ask the user.

Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already implemented.